# How to see the text of "read -p" when I execute a bash script thru ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh

I've this scenario:
I've a bash script in one server that execute a simple interactive menu.

If I run the script from he server itself I can see something like that:

```
$ bash menu.sh

Hi! Welcome to my menu.
1) Enter your name
2) Enter your age

Your choice:
```

If I press 1 I see the following.

```
Your choice: 1
Please enter your name:
```

So I can enter my name, press enter and the `menu.sh` continues...

To avoid tricky hands or something I need to avoid to enter to the server to run the menu. So I want to run the `menu.sh` externally.
Something like:

`ssh user@1.2.3.4 bash /path/to/menu.sh`

If I run the previous command I see the following as I expect:

```
Hi! Welcome to my menu.
1) Enter your name
2) Enter your age

Your choice:
```

But if I now press 1 I see nothing, but the `Please enter your name:`  is there wating for me to fill it. Just the connection doesn't send the `read -p "Please enter your name: "` content.

There is a way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `ssh` supports interactive sessions when using the command syntax.  You could set up a simple client + server with `nc`.  Or you could just `scp` `menu.sh` to your local box if it doesn't need to do any work on the remote box.

Comment: Try adding `-t` to the ssh command.

Comment: Great @jordanm! The `-t` argument solves the problem!!!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @0x5453, but the menu interacts with the server, so the file must run from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jordanm suggested add `-t`to ssh command does the trick!

> Try adding -t to the ssh command